# why there is meta tag in json response in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5.1

I confused very much. Please help me.

I have this java script code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#requestButton').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{job:'propertyCreation' },
                url: "/testajax", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data.responseText);

                },//success
                error:function(e){
                    alert(e.responseText);
                }
            }//ajax
        );//ajax
    });
});
```

Testajax function in my controller is responsible for answering to above ajax request.

```css
public function testajax(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')){
        $result=array('success'=>true,'response'=>$_REQUEST['job']);
 return json_encode($result);
    }

}
```

I expected that the response be

```html
{"success":true,"response":"propertyCreation"}
```

but response is

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
{"success":true,"response":"propertyCreation"}
```

I confused why there is meta tag in json response and the result has error not success. sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have multiple route files and in two route files in first of codes there was this line:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

After removing this lines, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in Laraver 5.2 and everything is OK.
Just one thing. According to JSON you have a little mistake in JavaScript in "alert" line:

```
// ...
success: function(data)
{
    // Should be => alert(data.response);
    alert(data.responseText); 
},//success
// ...
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answering. my codes works correctly in my other projects but in current project happens this problem. i do not know what I must do to solve that

Comment: Just right now I also tested it on clear Laravel 5.1 and it's OK too.
Maybe reason in a some middleware?

Comment: thank you Slam very very much for your attention and testing. thanks again. I find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What is returned value if you console.log(data)?

FYI, you should not use `json_encode` to send a JSON response in Laravel. Just `return $someArray` and it will be automatically encoded to JSON format.